# How to measure how exactly a column matches a pattern?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to have the results of my full text search in MySQL sorted by how completely the pattern covers the match.

For example searching for apple in a nutrition database should sort "apple, raw" higher than "apple fritter" since 5/9 > 5/12.

I can do this rather trivially outside the database, but i'm looking for a query that'll do it in one shot.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: I see the spirit of the question, however, the rule used in the example seems arbitrary with regards to the searched concept ('apple'), here.  With this kind of rule, 'apple,organically grown' would rank far below 'apple, bag' which well... is off.

Comment: @mjv - If he's concerned about string length in the database, his search methodology fine.  If Allain is concerned about deriving nutritional value from a text string, I think he's barking up the wrong tree. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORDER BY char_length(someColumn)/char_length(replace(someColumn, 'apple', ''))`

Comment: Possible bug, when someColumn contains just 'apple'.  consider reversing the fraction and sorting DESC

Comment: Performance improvement tip:  use   ...  char_length(somecolumn) - char_length('apple') rather than the replace() construct.  Assuming that 'apple' will be found somewhere in some_column (implicit to the search criteria applied in where clause) this allows to avoid all the computation of replace()